# How to know the number of displayed lines of the "cat" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How to know the number of displayed lines of the following "cat" command?

```
cat anyfile.txt | grep anypattern
```

Using `| wc -l` will avoid the display of the command output. And I want to keep the output displayd

Comment: Don't use `cat anyfile.txt | grep anypattern`, just use `grep anypattern anyfile.txt`.

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? Do you want to store the number in a variable, or do you want it to be displayed - and if so, how should it be displayed to be different from the output of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it while still using grep:

```
grep "anypattern" anyfile.txt | awk 'END{print NR}1'
```

**EDIT: To save count of lines in a shell variable:**

**Method 1:**

```
count=$(grep "anypattern" anyfile.txt | awk 'END{print NR > "/dev/stderr"}1' 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

**Method 2:**

```
grep "anypattern" anyfile.txt | awk 'END{print NR > "/tmp/_temp"}1'
count=$(</tmp/_temp)
```

Comment: how to save the number of lines into a variable and do not display it with the output of the `grep "anypattern" anyfile.txt`?

Comment: We can definitely save the variable in awk itself. Do you want to display search results also while saving the variable in shell?

Comment: Yes I want to keep displayng the command output. and save the number of line into a variable and do not display it

Comment: ok got it, I will edit my answer in few mins as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: You're welcome, I have added 2 methods to save the count in a shell variable: 1st is 1 step process without creating a file and 2nd is 2 step process with creation of a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep anypattern anyfile | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```

This will pipe the output of [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html) to [`tee`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) which will then write it both to standard output `stdout` and standard error `stderr`, and finally standard error will get displayed while standard output will get piped to [`wc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29) which will display the number of lines.

---

Example :

```
grep stack /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l

haystack
smokestack
stack
stacked
stacking
stack's
stacks
7
```

Comment: how to save the number of lines into a variable and do not display it with the output of the cat command?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
awk '/anypattern/{x++;print};END{print x}' anyfile.txt
```

Comment: +1, I would go this way too. but beware that, if the grep with `-P`, the "anypattern" may not work with `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tee` to redirect into `wc`:

```
printf "    line %d\n" {1..4} | tee >(wc -l)
```

```
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
    line 4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep anypattern anyfile.txt 1>&2 | wc -l
```

the expression `1>&2` instructs `bash` to duplicate `stdout` (fd=1) in a way that everything what is written from the previous command to `stdout` goes to `stderr` (fd=2) as well.

Since the redirection operator `|` writes everything that originates from `stdout` to the `stdin` of the following command you see the ouput of `stderr` on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

The *cat* command concatenates files, so unless you're invoking cat on a single file (which is a [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)) your line numbers won't mean anything useful anyway after the first file has been read. You can see this in action first-hand by using the `--number` flag with GNU cat.

### Use *cat* from GNU Coreutils

If you're using GNU cat, then you can just use the `--number` flag. For example:

```
$ cat --number <(echo one) <(echo two)
     1  one
     2  two
```

This will display the output, along with its current line number in the output stream. Note that this is entirely sequential: in this example, even though "two" is the first line of the second file, it is line number two of the concatenated output.

### Use Grep Flags Directly

If you're using GNU grep, you can get filenames and line numbers for a collection of files quite easily. For example:

```
$ grep --line-number --with-filename root /etc/passwd /etc/group
/etc/passwd:1:root:x:0:0:root,,,:/root:/bin/bash
/etc/group:1:root:x:0:
```

GNU grep will handle single files, multiple files, and file globs, so there's no need at all for *cat*.